# How do I include native macOS fonts, such as Times Roman and Helvetica, into Windows OS?

Tags: windows, macos, fonts, typeface

I am using both `macOS Catalina` and `Windows 10`, but I usually use Mac more for work, and Windows for gaming.

I prefer Times Roman over Times New Roman.

I also like Helvetica more than Arial fonts. Sadly, these fonts are not included in Windows OS. Is there a way to manually add them to Windows?

Helvetica can be easily added and found online, however the situation with other built-in macOS fonts, such as Times Roman and others (that are not included in Windows) is a bit harder. I couldn't have found those fonts online.

Is there a way over this, for example copying these fonts from Mac directory to a flash drive, and then adding them to Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way over this, for example copying these fonts from Mac
>   directory to a flash drive, and then adding them to Windows?

You'll need to download the fonts.

1. Install a bitTorrent client.
2. Click on this link https://thepiratebay.org/, and browse for a font torrent.
3. Download the torrent w/ your bitTorrent client.
4. Double click or drag the font(s) to the destination folder (under C:\WINNT\FONTS or C:\WINDOWS).

The font(s) will be added to your machine.